# How can I know that 11.10 won't introduce hardware compatibility problems?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to quickly and thoroughly use a LiveCD to test for hardware incompatibility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122445/how-to-quickly-and-thoroughly-use-a-livecd-to-test-for-hardware-incompatibility)

I haven't upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 yet & I am wary of doing it. I'm afraid that the upgrade will mess up my Thinkpad X120e's wireless or some other hardware component that I've had trouble with in the past (but managed to get working somehow).

How can I know that my hardware won't start going glitchy after the upgrade? Is there something about Ubuntu's testing process that might assure me, or should I just wait for reports from other X120e owners (aka guinea pigs) to come in before I make the leap myself?

Comment: I've owned this laptop, I'd be wary given the wireless card in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dry run**. Take the LiveCD and test it *extensively* on your system. Usually the drivers on the LiveCD will work the same when installed, even for upgrades. This won't guarantee that an distribution update glitch isn't introduced later, but at least ensures the initial compatibility state.

Also test the desktop environment for some time. Only upgrade if it's to your liking (the Gnome3 thing is widely unloved for example). Remember that neither of the two versions is a LTS.

That being said, your X120e https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBM_ThinkPad_X120e#Wireless does have fairly standard hardware. So I wouldn't be too worried.