# How to quickly and thoroughly use a LiveCD to test for hardware incompatibility?

Tags: hardware, live-cd

Often people wanting to know if Ubuntu will run on a potential hardware purchase are advised to use the LiveCD, perhaps in-store, to check hardware compatibility.  For example, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/67929/43660) suggests drivers will usually not be an issue if they work off the LiveCD, but it also says to test "extensively".

Given that if you do this in-store, you'll have a limited time period to do the testing, what is the most efficient way to test the computer?  For example, after running a program like vlc to check video and audio...is it then necessary to try a music player too?  What settings should be checked?

Let's assume I am interested in all the usual laptop functions (suspend, hibernate, wireless), in addition to things like built-in webcam, microphone, etc.

Also, if the laptop doesn't have an optical drive (like some of the newer thin laptops), then I would have to boot from USB.  Is this just as reliable as testing from the CD?  (I feel silly asking this, but I know some laptops behave differently booting from USB, e.g. Apple)

Comment: practically it is impossible ,because live cd /dvd need more resource than hdd installation ,still system testing app is helpful

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16666/diagnose-hardware-problems-with-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't design a persistent USB drive to do this. You could preload it applications and audio/video of your liking. Testing wireless would be a piece of cake. The only thing I imagine might be a hangup would be graphics, as those types of changes are not persistent.

Comment: Suspending is accomplishable, but you must set the USB as the first boot device in bios.

Comment: I do not think there is a quick way. You identify the hardware, boot Ubuntu, confirm the hardware is or is not working. Most problems arise from video cards, wireless cards, and less often audio or web cams. So, when you boot, does X work? is the resolution correct, can you connect to wireless, and stream audio. Bring a test file on a flash drive and play it. Try the webcam. Should be straightforward.

Comment: I guess the key is to have a list of what to test, maybe a testsuite on an USB stick. Being prepared, and have - for example - a video for testing available; knowing where to find audio files on the live-cd.

Comment: Quickly and thoroughly often don't make sense together. A thorough testing using the Live CD implies it's going to take a while. That said, gaining experience through practice, and knowing what to test can speed up the process. Hardware that needs proprietary drivers often can't be tested from Live CDs, but in that case, you can, at least, get the chipset to look up later.

Comment: Great suggestions here...If anyone wants to summarize them as a single answer, I'd be happy to mark it solved.  I particularly like the idea of designing a preloaded USB, although I don't know how suspend would work there (will they let me play with the BIOS?  Probably not).

Yeah, it'd be nice to have that experience of what to test, but my idea was that with advice I'd need less :-)

Comment: There is this awesome drive that does hardware emulation of .iso files, that a way you could put your live cd's on there, and know it boots exactly like a real cd would, http://www.zalman.com/eng/product/Product_Read.asp?idx=431 would probally even work on mac.

Comment: It should be noted that this will not test the HDD (specifically, SSD) compatibility. Something that became an issue for me in 12.10 (but not in 12.04 nor 13.04).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to run through the Ubuntu Friendly Test Suite.  Simply search for "Friendly" in the Apps lens, and run the "System Testing" app.  This already has all hardware related cases, and is a quick, easy way to test through all hardware enablement test cases.  More info can be found here: https://friendly.ubuntu.com/participate/

Comment: Hi Chris.  Looks good! +1 for now... I'll accept this after I check this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need Checkbox test suite in this case: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation/Checkbox

Also create a [hw-probe](https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe) of the computer to investigate system logs for hardware related errors.