# Radeon hd 5450 and kubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: kubuntu, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to quickly and thoroughly use a LiveCD to test for hardware incompatibility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122445/how-to-quickly-and-thoroughly-use-a-livecd-to-test-for-hardware-incompatibility)

I Wonder, Can Radeon HD 5450 handle Kubuntu 12.04 LTS? i would like to know before i actually the entire fully kubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mobility Radeon HD 5470 installed in my secondary notebook and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS works without any qualms. This might be anecdotal evidence at best but I personally don't see any reason why Kubuntu wouldn't run on your graphics card as well.

I recommend installing the proprietary drivers (`FGLRX`), though, as they significantly improved the battery life on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you that before installing you used the LiveCD so you can use it normally and check how does your Graphic card works.